# It's not possible to vertically scroll to the top of the form in a certain height dimension

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a basic form with bootstrap and when re-sizing the screen (in height), it's not possible to scroll to the top of the form.

Please see the link: http://jsbin.com/semamimitu/edit?html,css,output

Notice when you resize in height, after a certain height it is possible to scroll all the way down to the form, but not to the top.

How can I have the logo and the rest of the form always visible and scrollable even when the height of the screen is less than the form itself?

Solutions with javascript, besides css are also fine.

Comment: There you go : http://jsbin.com/padaluraxi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

see the changes in form-register

```
.form-register {
    max-width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/gubugacevu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: It's not centered in the middle of t he screen. It's positioned to the top of the screen and not the center. By center I mean, center of the screen, horizontally and vertically. 
But you're almost there.